# Use code from another solution that is still in development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This may be a trivial question, but how do I use code from a project of a different solution than the one I am currently working in? Mind you that the code I want to use is still under development. These are the solutions I have explored:

- Right-click solution and add the project to this solution as an existing project.
- Add a reference to the debug/release dll containing the code I need.

I like the first option, since it allows me to view the structure and source of the project from which I am using code. Furthermore it does not matter whether the project is built with Debug or Release; the latest code will be used automatically. The downside (a big one in my opinion) is that I am able to edit this project from within my new solution.

The second option removes the possibility to accidentally edit the project code, however here I am stuck with either selecting the Debug or the Release version of the dll I need. This does not appeal to me.

So, is there a third option that combines the best of these two methods or am I completely missing something?

Comment: Do you have version control ? You could branch your development code. Then you can do a merge when the development code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same problem in our development environment. The solution we use is not to build to the `bin` folder, but to a different folder outside the scope of the current project. Every project outputs its files there (it is also used for version control). From that location, you can include the assembly.

When you change `Debug` to `Release`, the file will be updated automatically. No need to switch to another folder.

Comment: @trans: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the .dll from the otherproject/Debug/Release
Or even better: Add a postbuild Script to 'otherproject' so that the release .dll always gets copied in your 'library' directory.

Answer (score 0):

> The downside (a big one in my opinion) is that I am able to edit this project from within my new solution.

On the other hand, the upside is that you are able to edit this project from within the new solution. Why would you make a change to that project that it doesn't need?

If the project is very young, I'd prefer to have it as source for this very reason. Add the unit test project for that project to your solution as well, and then you are able to improve the project in the context of more than one solution it is intended to serve.

If the project is not very young, then I would suggest distributing the binary with a private nuget server. They are very quick to set up, low-cost (they need a machine that can run a webserver, and will not be resource-heavy on that machine), and it makes using your own assemblies as simple as using any other nuget package.